# Excel - Countifs, but only count uniques based on different column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, count, unique

I want to use countifs to count the amount of entries in a table, but I only want it to count once if another cell is repeated. The following is an example:

In the table:

[image]

I want to count the amount of "a" in column N, but only once for each time a specific number appears. So, in this example, if I want to count the amount of "a", it would be 1, because every other reoccurrence of "a" in N has a 1 in column M.

If there was an entre with 5 in M and "a" in N, it would return 2, as this entry of "a" has a unique value in M.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

With Office 365:

```
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(M:M,N:N="a")))
```

Older versions:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((N1:N100="a")/(COUNTIFS(N1:N100,"a",M1:M100,M1:M100)+(N1:N100<>"a")))
```